# Aparecer uma mensagem enquanto não traz os resultados do banco de dados

Tags: jquery

Colegas,

Infelizmente não tenho nenhum código para essa dúvida, pois não conheço muito jquery, porém tenho uma página onde trago os resultados de um banco de dados mysql, só que em alguns casos o resultado demora um pouco para aparecer. Como eu faria para que aparecesse uma mensagem (aguarde, dados sendo processados) ou gif de carregamento eqto os resultados não aparecem?

Estou trazendo os resultados da seguinte forma:

**Página visualizar-usuarios.php**

```
<html>
.....
<h2>Relação dos usuários cadastrados</h2>
<?php echo $metodos->visualizarUsuarios(); ?>
.....
</html>
```

Dentro de **$metodos->visualizarUsuarios()** trago os resultados de uma query de forma procedural usando o mysqli_().

```
public function visualizarUsuarios(){
 ....
  $sqlVisualizar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM visualizar_usuarios");

  while($jmVisualizar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlVisualizar)){
    // Resultados  
  }  

}
```

Comment: Você está carregando os dados via Ajax?

Comment: Olá Artur, não estamos usando carregamento via Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Basta você mandar exibir a mensagem antes de ir fazer a requisição ao banco e depois você oculta a mensagem quando retornar os dados (resposta de sucesso ou erro), exemplo abaixo é via ajax. Poste como você está fazendo estas requisições no banco para que possa te auxiliar melhor.

```js
function processar(){
  $('#aguarde').show();
  $.ajax( 'https://httpbin.org/delay/2' )
    .done(function() {
      alert('Terminou o processamento');
      $('#aguarde').hide();
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert('Terminou o processamento - ERRO');
      $('#aguarde').hide();
    });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="processar()">Processar</button>
<div id="aguarde" style="display:none">Aguarde, estamos processando</div>
```

Comment: Olá Hugo. Alterei o meu post incluindo as informações solicitadas.